# Load Lazy collection by values from predefined array

Tags: .net, lazy-loading

Assume i have Lazy collection which i want preload in some cases( by preload i mean take some values and make wrap them by Lazy collection)

```
var lazyCollection = new Lazy<T[]>(() => ....);
var TCollection = GetTValues().ToArray();
```

How to make something like `lazyCollection = TCollection` or  `lazyCollection = new Lazy<T[]>(TCollection)` ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you already have the values, why use `Lazy`?

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth  Because of i need to rewrite a big part of code(in case of i remove Lazy and use just a List)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use something like this:

```
var lazyCollection = new Lazy<T[]>(() => TCollection);
```